# Regex match string grouping at start of line

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, markdown

I have a markdown string like so:

```
var str = "
  # Title here
  Some body of text
  ## A subtitle
  ##There may be no space after the title hashtags
  Another body of text with a Twitter #hashtag in it";
```

Now I want to match and replace all title hashtags to add another hashtag to them. BUT I need to avoid matching the hashtag in the line of text (the twitter hashtag). I am trying to achieve the following string:

```
var str = "
  ## Title here
  Some body of text
  ### A subtitle
  ###There may be no space after the title hashtags
  Another body of text with a Twitter #hashtag in it";
```

So far I've got this regex, which does the job but also matches the twitter hashtag:

```
str = str.replace(/(#+)/g, "$1#");
```

There are carriage returns after each line of text. How do I achieve this replace without affecting hashtags in the text.

Comment: Is your `var str = ...` a valid JS syntax?

Comment: @anubhava It sure isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `/m`, you can use `^` to match the start of the line (without the `/m`, it only matches the start of the entire string).
You can then use `\s*` (thanks stribizhev) to preserve all whitespaces at the beginning of every line.

```
str = str.replace(/^\s*#+/gm, "$&#");
```

Demo:

```js
// Note that multiline strings are not actually legal in JavaScript
var str = [
'  # Title here',
'  Some body of text',
'  ## A subtitle',
'  ##There may be no space after the title hashtags',
'  Another body of text with a Twitter #hashtag in it'
].join('\n');
document.write(str.replace(/^\s*#+/gm, "$&#"));
```

```css
/* For demo only */
body{white-space:pre-line;font-family:monospace}
```

Comment: I guess `\s*` should be used or those lines that have no leading spaces will not be modified. And there is no need enclosing the whole pattern into a capturing group, use `$&` backreference.

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, thanks for that, edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed